# SQL turn combinations of values into columns that log combination's existence or not

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a PSQL table of results like so:

| ID | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Red |
| 123 | Blue |
| 456 | Green |
| 789 | Red |
| 789 | Green |

I would like to return the results in the following view:

| ID | Red | Green | Blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | X |  | X |
| 456 |  | X |  |
| 789 | X | X |  |

where an 'X' represents that the combination of ID and Color exists in my original results table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation. For example:

```
select
  id,
  max(case when color = 'Red' then 'X' end) as red,
  max(case when color = 'Green' then 'X' end) as green,
  max(case when color = 'Blue' then 'X' end) as blue
from t
group by id
```

Comment: This is rad. Let's say my value combinations are potentially very long, instead of just "Red," "Green" and "Blue." In order to avoid many lines of `max(case when ...)`s, is there a way to do a dynamic select to return all the value combinations?

Comment: The answer would be 'yes' but that's not what your question is specifically about; you could get a list of distinct values and then dynamically build a sql query - look for questions about dynamic pivot for guidance.

Comment: "Pivoting" with a dynamic number of columns cannot be done in plain SQL, but using Dynamic SQL instead. As @Stu mentioned you can write a stored procedure that inspects the table for the number of columns, then assembles a tailored SQL query for it, and runs it.